# can i read windows-1256 file in java?

Tags: java, character-encoding

**I want to read an Arabic text file encoded in windows-1256 using Java (on the windows platform)**

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*If* your JVM supports that encoding, then yes, you can easily do that:

```
Reader r = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(theFile), "Windows-1256");
BufferedReader buffered = new BufferedReader(r);
try {
  String line;
  while ((line = buffered.readLine()) != null) {
    // handle each line
  }
} finally {
  buffered.close();
}
```

Comment: Should be no problem, also my Mac supports Windows-1256

Comment: @Arne: I only mentioned the "if" because Windows-1256 is not one of the [6 encodings that all JVMs must support](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) (specifically those are US-ASCII, ISO-8859-1, UTF-8, UTF-16BE, UTF-16LE and UTF-16).

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                       new FileInputStream("myfile.txt"), "windows-1256"));
```

Should work.

Answer (score 0):

To read from a FileInputStream with another character set than the platform default, use an InputStreamReader:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader(java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String)